# c# custom control winform

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls

c# custom control 
winproc how

wndproc
How can i override it ?
How can i do winproc function in custom control  and how can i catch coming messages ?

Comment: What do you want to do with your custom control's `WndProc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to WinForms, override the `Control.WndProc` method, and do something there.

Comment: How can i do winproc function in custom control  and how can i catch coming messages ?

Comment: Do what I said in the answer. There's an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx